# JWT validation fails in second try

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa

I have the following C# code in my application and I am concerned about push this to production because it seems like a bug in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens:

```
        public static TrustedCredential Validate(string token, string applicationId, string publicKey)
        {
            TrustedCredential result = TryToValidate(token, applicationId, publicKey);

            if (ReferenceEquals(result, null))
            {
                result = TryToValidate(token, applicationId, publicKey);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static TrustedCredential TryToValidate(string token, string applicationId, string publicKey)
        {
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler;
            ClaimsPrincipal claims;
            string sub, name, email, tenantId;
            
            RSA rsa = null;

            try
            {
                rsa = RSA.Create();

                rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);

                validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "codeconecta",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = applicationId,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

                handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                sub = claims.FindFirst(MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames.Sub).Value;
                email = claims.FindFirst(MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames.Email).Value;
                tenantId = claims.FindFirst(MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames.TenantId).Value;
                name = claims.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name).Value;

                return new TrustedCredential(tenantId, sub, email, name);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (rsa != null)
                {
                    rsa.Dispose();
                    rsa = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note that the Validate method tries twice, because I get the exception on the first attempt but not on the second one.

*Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: 'IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.*

EDIT 1:
This is the code to generate JWT:

```
SigningCredentials signingCredentials;
JwtSecurityToken token;

JwtHeader jwtHeader;
JwtPayload jwtPayload;
            
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

    jwtHeader = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);

    jwtHeader["kid"] = "some_kid_value";

    jwtPayload = new JwtPayload (
        issuer: "codeconecta",
        audience: connectedApp.id,
        claims: claims,
        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
    );

    token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload);

    return (new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()).WriteToken(token);
}
```

This is MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames class:

```
internal class MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames
{
    internal const string Sub = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";
    internal const string Email = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";
    internal const string TenantId = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid";
}
```

Comment: `catch (SecurityTokenException)` <-- Why aren't you examining the exception? - and why are you using your own `try/catch` for `rsa` instead of a `using` block?

Comment: The error message is straightforward: why don't your JWTs have `kid` claims? (Yes, the specs say it's optional, but it makes everything work better).

Comment: Pleaase show us your `MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames` - I'm curious what claim-names you're usiing...

Comment: @Dai, I'm not examining exception because this code is not finished yet. This is some piece of code to test the desired behavior.
The try / catch / finally with rsa is some alternative code (I've already tested with "using" structure... same results)

Comment: @Dai I'm generating JWT with kid header. I'm editing the question right now to put the piece of code where I get JWT

Comment: @Dai, just edited the question to put MicrosoftRegisteredClaimNames class too

Comment: As far as I know, a `kid` is required when you have multiple keys, but in your example you just have one public key